# Frequency counts of all possibilities in R

Tags: r

I want to analyze the frequency counts of a data set.
I have 6 balls, numbered 1 to 6.
3 balls are drawn from a box without replacement and the numbers are noted.
The 3 balls are returned in the box and the process is repeated 5 times.
I want to analyze the frequency counts of one number, two numbers and three numbers.
One number
1-
2-
3-
4-
5-
6-
Two numbers
(1,2)
(1,3)
6C2=15 combinations
Three numbers
(1,2,3)
(1,2,4)
6C3=20 combinations

There is my data set.

```
df = as.data.frame(rbind(c(1,3,5), c(3,4,5), c(2,4,6), c(1,3,6), c(2,4,5)))
colnames(df) = c("num1","num2","num3")

  num1 num2 num3
1    1    3    5
2    3    4    5
3    2    4    6
4    1    3    6
5    2    4    5
```

I am new in R. Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks, 
Babajee D K R

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Users will be able to provide better advice if you also describe what you have attempted already (including code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some very inelegant solution, but it does the job:

```
library(tidyverse)

#One number

one_numb <- combn(names(df), 1, simplify = FALSE)

result <- list()

for(i in 1:length(one_numb)) {
 result[[i]] <- df %>%
  mutate(comb = paste0(!!as.symbol(one_numb[[i]][1]))) %>%
  select(comb)
}

bind_rows(result) %>%
 group_by(comb) %>%
 tally()

  comb      n
  <chr> <int>
1 1         2
2 2         2
3 3         3
4 4         3
5 5         3
6 6         2

#Two numbers

two_numb <- combn(names(df), 2, simplify = FALSE)

result <- list()

for(i in 1:length(two_numb)) {
 result[[i]] <- df %>%
 mutate(comb = paste0(!!as.symbol(two_numb[[i]][1]), !!as.symbol(two_numb[[i]][2]))) %>%
 select(comb)
}

bind_rows(result) %>%
 group_by(comb) %>%
 tally()

   comb      n
   <chr> <int>
 1 13        2
 2 15        1
 3 16        1
 4 24        2
 5 25        1
 6 26        1
 7 34        1
 8 35        2
 9 36        1
10 45        2
11 46        1

#Three numbers

three_numb <- combn(names(df), 3, simplify = FALSE)

result <- list()

for(i in 1:length(three_numb)) {
 result[[i]] <- df %>%
  mutate(comb = paste0(!!as.symbol(three_numb[[i]][1]), !!as.symbol(three_numb[[i]][2]), 
                       !!as.symbol(three_numb[[i]][3]))) %>%
  select(comb)
}

bind_rows(result) %>%
 group_by(comb) %>%
 tally()

  comb      n
  <chr> <int>
1 135       1
2 136       1
3 245       1
4 246       1
5 345       1
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. I want to show the combinations for 2 numbers to be displayed by    comb      n
   <chr> <int>
 1 1,3        2
 2 1,5        1
 3 1,6        1  separated by comma

Comment: Then try `mutate(comb = paste(!!as.symbol(two_numb[[i]][1]), !!as.symbol(two_numb[[i]][2]), sep = ","))`.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I would like to sort the combination of two numbers in ascending order   comb      n
   <chr> <int>
 1 1,3        2
 2 2,4        2
 3 3,5        2
 4 4,5        2

Comment: You can do  `tally() %>%
 arrange(n)`.

Comment: Thanks. It is great. I have used excel (sumproduct) to generate these statistics. Now i will be using R.  I would like to know how to find the sum of frequency for the two number (15) and how to read the frequency of two number (3,5) and which draw they appear?

Comment: These are separate problems, please create additional questions. Also, if my post solved your original problem, please accept it.